# Path/Configuration problem with Qt SDK and Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, path, qt4, codeblocks

I'm new to Code::Blocks (nice IDE!) and to Qt with C++ (been using PyQt, which works wonderfully)

I have a test project - here's the code (generated by code::blocks wizard):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPushButton quit("Quit");
    quit.resize(75, 30);
    quit.setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    QObject::connect(&quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    quit.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I BELIEVE I have the search path for Qt4 configured correctly in code::blocks, but when I try to run this code I get the below listed errors - so obviously I'm missing something - either my paths are in correct or my installation is corrupt. For my Qt installation I used Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_1_2_en.exe, found on the Qt website - installed the entire Qt SDK in D:, so the root path for the Qt installation is D:\QtSDK..

Any help on how to fix this configuration would be appreciated - I am excited about using Qt with C++ after fighting with Win32s/MFC/.NET etc etc for so many years....

***Errors:***

> ||=== QtTest, Debug ===|
>
> obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|7|undefined reference to >`*imp*__ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN11QPushButtonC1ERK7QStringP7QWidget'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN5QFontC1ERK7QStringiib'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN7QWidget7setFontERK5QFont'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN5QFontD1Ev'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN5QFontD1Ev'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `*imp*__Z13qFlagLocationPKc'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `*imp*__Z13qFlagLocationPKc'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN7QObject7connectEPKS_PKcS1_S3_N2Qt14ConnectionTypeE'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QApplication4execEv'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN11QPushButtonD1Ev'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN11QPushButtonD1Ev'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'|
>
> E:\ResourceBrowse\QtTest\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'|
>   obj\Debug\main.o||In function`QString':|
>
> D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtCore\qstring.h|426|undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci'|
>   obj\Debug\main.o||In function`~QString':|
>
> D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtCore\qstring.h|883|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN7QString4freeEPNS_4DataE'|
>
> obj\Debug\main.o:D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtGui\qwidget.h|1001|undefined reference to 
>   `*imp*__ZN7QWidget6resizeERK5QSize'|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 17 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Comment: what libraries did you pass to the linker? Can you add that info to the post? From what I can make out of the mangled names, it can't find QApplication, QPushButton, QFont etc. Are you linking the Qt library statically or dynamically? The `_imp__*` likely indicates the linker's looking for an import library for dynamic linkage.

Comment: @Victor - thanks for answering - I just followed the code::blocks defaults for a Qt project - it prompted me for location of the Qt libs and took it from there. I checked in the project options and I see there's nothing in the linker paths - will try manually entering the paths to Qt in there.

Comment: Linker points to: QtCore4;QtGui4 - and when I go to edit them, they point to the correct directories - where Qt is installed. Also added explicit paths in the 'other search paths' option. Still the same. Something is missing....

Comment: I think the other thing that'll help is pasting the build commands and switches code::blocks actually used. You can turn this on under *Settings->Compiler/Debug settings->Global Compiler settings->Other settings tab*. From there set Compiler Logging to Full commandline. The build logs will show the commands getting invoked the next time you compile the project.

Comment: fyi, most of the unresolved functions from your posted errors should exist in QtGuid4.dll & QtGui4.dll.

Comment: Thanks again Victor - I'll try to get it to work. I think this is a CodeBlocks problem because I used their wizard to generate the test code and pointed it to the right Qt path. When I tried posting this on the CodeBlocks website, I had to register but so many bot checkers and captchas I flunked the tests three times and gave up! They holding military secrets there or something? Never saw a site with so many tests! (actually I don't think the military is that careful...) Could use QtCreator but I want to work in generic C++ IDE, not with a Nokia/Qt tool. Maybe I should try CodeLite...

Comment: Regardless, thanks for all the explicit instructions.

Comment: So far no luck - but I had installed first PyQt, then Code::Blocks, which installed the GNU compiler, then QT SDK, which again installed another GNU compiler (I thought it would detect the one Code::Blocks installed but it didn't) so I think things were pretty mixed up on the configuration of that workstation. So, I'm nuking everything: will scrub the registry and then start from scratch - first with Qt SDK, then Code::Blocks. BTW-maybe you'll weigh in on this question I put up: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95448/codeblocks-vs-codelite-vs-qtcreator - Thanks again.

Comment: ```obj\Debug\main.o:D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtGui\qwidget.h|1001|undefined reference to `imp__ZN7QWidget6resizeERK5QSize'|```

MSVC library with MinGW (CB) compiler? And did you add ```debug``` libs? I mean you should add ```QtCored4.dll, QtGuid4.dll``` etc. For release build, skip the 'd' in linkers. I am doing small Qt tests with C::B (Windows and Linux) for years.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have too much time spend on this. I used GTK instead, which works fine and does what I need.